# Web Services client issue

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, webservice-client

I have a single WebMethod which will return List object as shown below

```
[WebMethod]
        public List<ContactMaster> GetContacts()
        {
            //ContactMaster contact = new ContactMaster();

            List<ContactMaster> contacts=new List<ContactMaster>();


            IQueryable<ContactMaster> contact = from c in db.ContactMasters
                                    select c;

            foreach (ContactMaster c in contact)
            {
                contacts.Add(c);

            }

            return  contacts ;
        }
```

When I try to invoke the same method from client I am getting an error as follows

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException
```

Comment: Let's see the code you use on the client to invoke it as well.

Comment: Also, is ContactMaster Serializable?

Comment: This is not the solution but your whole method could be re-written as this: `return db.ContactMasters.ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has an article for troubleshooting xml serialization issues.  There's too much info to post here.  I'd start at their article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx).

However, step 1 should be to try to get to the Inner Exception, which should be more specific.